# How to import images under Solution notes in Case

Tags: images, case-object

We recently migrated the data from one org to another org... In the old org for some cases there were images embedded in the Solution notes section. We were able to migrate the text under the solution notes but not the image..
Question:
1. Is there a way to identify if a solution notes has an image or not?
2. How do we migrate the images under solution notes from one org to other org?

Comment: Am guessing here, but there may be an issue with the links you're calling them from where they reference the wrong instance if you're using absolute links. If they're relative links, make certain you have them in the same location so the paths are the same.